# windowManager.updateViewLayout does not update view x and y coordinates?

Tags: android, android-view, android-windowmanager

I am trying to create test application similar to Facebook chat heads. In this i am using window manager to add and update view dynamically to the screen and when user select the image then it should show expanded list with some content. To show the contents i am using popup window class.

When user select the view then i am showing expanded view from specific location. suppose current view location is x = 736 & y = 1124. If user want to see the content then user will select the view then i re-draw all views from specific location suppose x = 700 and y = 50 so that i can get the space in screen to show popup window.

**Problem : - When i update the views using windowManager.updateViewLayout method it updates the view on screen but view.getLocationOnScreen(location) still returns the old coordinates due to that my popup window is not drawn correctly as pop up window is  not having enough space in screen.**

Ex : - My current view location is x = 736 & y = 1124 and once user selects the view, i am redrwing all the views to new location x = 700 and y = 50, but when i do view.getLocationOnScreen(location) i am still getting x = 736 & y = 1124. which is incorrect.

Solution tried : - requestLayout() to force re-draw the screen before calculating the getLocationOnScreen.

```
    expandedParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    expandedParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
            expandedParams.x = 700;
    expandedParams.y = 50;

    for (int i = chatHeadsImageview.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    //getting width of my view
        expandedParams.x = expandedParams.x
                - chatHeadsImageview.get(i).getWidth();
                    //Storing current update x location
        chatHeadsImageview.get(i).setxOpenChatHeadCordinate(
                expandedParams.x);
                    //Storing current update y location
        chatHeadsImageview.get(i).setyOpenChatHeadCordinate(
                expandedParams.y);
                    //updating the view
        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHeadsImageview.get(i),
                expandedParams);

    }

    int[] location = new int[2];
                     chatHeadsImageview.get(chatHeadsImageview.size()-1).getLocationOnScreen(location);
    System.out.println("getLocationOnScreen  x ==> "+location[0]);
    System.out.println("getLocationOnScreen  y ==> "+location[1]);
```

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: HI i have solved this problem by using view.post(runnable) method. Now my pop up view will wait till the time my chatHeadImage is not drawn.